# Html.CheckBox returning value not true/false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

This seems ridicouous but can you only return true/false from an MVC checkbox? I remember back in the day (in classic asp) it was perfectly valid to return a value from a ticked checkbox but Microsoft appears to of decided that checkboxes should only contain true/false value.

So if you add the following:

```
@Html.CheckBox("PropertyTypes", true, new {@value="A"})
```

I would expect my form POST to contain `Property=A`, what I end up with is`Property=A&Property=true` which then breaks the model so I get a `null` in the property rather than the string I wanted.

On investigation it turns out this is because microsoft adds an extra input for so *I get a false if I don't want to check the input*...gee thanks a lot......:/

```
<input id="PropertyTypes" type="checkbox" value="Hotel" name="PropertyTypes" data-val-youmustselectatleastone="You must select at least one Property Type" data-val="true" checked="checked">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="PropertyTypes">
```

**WHY!**

I could just code in an input myself just using flat HTML but then I loose all my unobtrusive validation.

any ideas on how to get around this stupidity?

Ps the number of checkboxes is dynamic so adding a property for each value isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @KristianHellang How can I return a value from a tickbox? Not true or false?

Comment: A checkbox is either checked/unchecked, e.g. true/false. Sure you don't want a dropdown? ;)

Comment: You have to create an HTML extension that adds validation attributes I think.

Comment: @KristianHellang No, it's a UI thing. I want x number of tick boxes that the user can tick that then decide on what options they are searching for. So I want a hotel and/or a villa and/or a apartment, etc.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları any tutorials or pointers?

Comment: How about not using `@Html` helper and create checkbox manually?

Comment: @Liam Ah, I see. I've used the [MvcCheckBoxList](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcCheckBoxList) before. That could work... See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension)

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev That breaks the validation.

Comment: And here's the comment from source code: "Render an additional <input type="hidden".../> for checkboxes. This addresses scenarios where unchecked checkboxes are not sent in the request. Sending a hidden input makes it possible to know that the checkbox was present
on the page when the request was submitted."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This seems ridicouous but can you only return true/false from an MVC checkbox?

I don't find it ridiculous. When you give it a second thought modeling a checked/unchecked state with a boolean variable actually makes sense.

> WHY!

Because that's how the designers of the framework decided to implement the CheckBox helper.

> any ideas on how to get around this stupidity?

By using a view model of course:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

and then assuming you had a collection of those you would use a checkbox and a hidden field to store the corresponding id of the item:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SomeCollection[i].Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SomeCollection[i].IsChecked)
```

When the form is submitted you will get the collection property containing the ids of your items and whether they were selected or not.

Comment: So this breaks the W3C standard...http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html *Several checkboxes in a form may share the same control name. Thus, for example, checkboxes allow users to select several values for the same property. The INPUT element is used to create a checkbox control.*

Comment: No, this doesn't break any W3C standard. Feel free to pass your generated markup through the W3C validator and you will be happy :-)

Comment: Well thanks for the answer...I'm really angry at this for some reason....I may write MS an angry letter...that'll teach them! :)

Comment: Go ahead. You could also say a Welcome from me in your letter and tell them to remove ViewData/ViewBag in the next release :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I read about 10 different pages before finding this one. You explain it so simply. Now I can go and do some real work :)